# MDM:Check-in occurs 3 times in a Configuration profile

Tags: iphone, ios, configuration, utility, mdm

Thank you.

I am using Mac.

iPhone Configuration utility
The Configuration profile of
"qualification information" and "mobile device management" was summarized to one
,and the Configuration profile was created.

If the Configuration profile summarized to one is installed in an iOS terminal,
one check-in will have occurred continuously.

This is satisfactory.

But, when the "passcode" was added to this, the problem occurred.

iPhone Configuration utility 
The Configuration profile of a "passcode",
"qualification information",
and "mobile device management" was summarized to one,
and the Configuration profile was created.

If the Configuration profile summarized to one is installed in an iOS terminal,
three check-in will have occurred continuously.
**"MDM: Telling MDM Check-In Server about new device token."**

I want someone to teach what kind of thing this is.

```
Jul 10 10:16:24 unknown mdmd[16934] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: mdmd starting...
Jul 10 10:16:24 unknown mdmd[16934] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: Network reachability has changed.
Jul 10 10:16:24 unknown mdmd[16934] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: Network reachability has changed.
Jul 10 10:16:24 unknown mdmd[16934] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: Telling MDM Check-In Server about new device token.
Jul 10 10:16:25 unknown mdmd[16934] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: Transaction completed. Status: 200
Jul 10 10:16:25 unknown mdmd[16934] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: Telling MDM Check-In Server about new device token.
Jul 10 10:16:25 unknown mdmd[16934] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: Transaction completed. Status: 200
Jul 10 10:16:25 unknown mdmd[16934] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: Telling MDM Check-In Server about new device token.
Jul 10 10:16:25 unknown mdmd[16934] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: Transaction completed. Status: 200
Jul 10 10:16:27 unknown mdmd[16934] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: mdmd stopping...
```

Comment: I have seen this also but only twice. I think your only option is to write your code to gracefully handle multiple check-ins.

Comment: Thank you. 
The log was added. 
Please help me in order to solve.

Comment: Questions concerning MDM in iOS should be directed towards your vendor, or if you are the vendor; Apple.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same issue. please remove the old mdm configuration profile and try it might help.